# How important is a film shade to protect Polaroid photos when they first eject?

Tags: polaroid, instant-camera

My friend just got a Polaroid SX-70 Model 1 and has some old film stock. How important is a film shade to protect Polaroid photos when they first eject?

What about with the new films from The Impossible Project?

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this article at eHow.com](http://www.ehow.com/how-does_4886545_polaroid-film-work.html), I would be inclined to say no. I have not found any articles that describe in detail the polaroid development process, however the eHow article seems to be clear in the sense that there is an *opacifer* (light blocker) in the reagent. When the camera ejects the film, it spreads a reagent, comprised of white pigments, opacifers, and alkali over the film. The chemical process that ensues once the reagent is on the film culminates in an acid/alkali reaction that turns the opacifer transparent, allowing you to see the photograph.

Logically, it would have to work that way...regardless of whether the photograph was taken in sunlight or under artificial light. Any amount of light striking the film would ultimately affect exposure to one degree or another, ruining the photograph.